# What does this symbol represent?

Tags: analysis, gretel-and-hansel

In the movie *Gretel and Hansel* this screen shot is shown. I am wondering what symbolism it represents.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7iaK.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in [this blog post](http://www.truefreethinker.com/articles/symbolism-2020-gretel-hansel-movie), the triangle/pyramid shape is a reoccurring symbol in Gretel & Hansel:

[image]
[image]

The second is an obvious allusion to the '[Eye of Providence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_Providence)', originally a Christian symbol, but nowadays more often invoking associations with Freemasonry (especially the eye within a pyramid shape).

Less obvious - but still referencing it - is the shape of the witch's outfit:

[image]

Apart from these signs **alluding to alchemy and magic**, I can think of a few other reasons they could have been used:

- **To emphasize the symbolism or mysticism** of the film('s plot), rather than it being a straightforward story - it is a fairy-tale, after all.
- As **an allusion to the stereotypical witch's hat**.
- Purely **as branding**, or visually tying parts of the film together.
- (Art-)historically, the triangle/pyramid shape is a sign of hierarchy. I haven't seen the film, and it seems unlikely this plays a role here, but it could imply the imminent overthrow of the witch or a constant power struggle.

Comment: WoW, one of your points is right on. I will not spoil this movie for you.